# git commits with other github email?

Tags: ssh

I set up a work and personal github accounts.  To distinguish them I created a config file in ~/.ssh:

```
Host workusername.github.com
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host personalusername.github.com
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
User personalusername
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personalusername
```

I saved config and entered

> git config user.name "personalusername"

To my dismay commits look like:

```
personalusername <workemail>
```

the git username is not associated with the one I specify in github.com settings.

Answer (score 0):

git config user.email personalemail.  Close the terminal and open it again.